# Razor, how to create a input box and check what's inside

Tags: razor

I'd like to create an input box and check what's inside like if it's 1 i return a special page.

If someone could help me, lead me on the good way

Comment: when you want to do your check  ? on the page load ? Creating input element is simple as pasting this code in your view `<input type="text" />` .

Comment: I'd like to have a box where i write something and when i click on my button it shows me a specificate page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep your input field in a form with a submit button. In your form submit event,check the form field value and return the appropriate page you want.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  <input type="text" name="myVal" value="" />
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

Assuming the above code is inside the Create view(`~/Views/Customer/Create.cshtml`)  of Customer controller, You will need to add an HttpPost method to handle the form submit.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{ 
   return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(string myVal)
{
  if(myVal=="1")
  {
    // do a redirect to another action method
    return RedirectToAction("Index","Customer");
  }
  else
  {
    return Content("Entered value is not 1");
  }
}
```

Now when you submit the form after entering "1" in the input field, your action method will send a 302 response to the browser with location header set as `"yourSiteName/Customer/Index"`. Browser will then make a new GET request to this url.

Comment: Thanks, So i put the first code in my view and the second one in my controller ?

Comment: Yes. You need a GET action for rendering your view also. See my updated answer. After that. you access it like `yourSite/YourControllerName/Create` in a browser.

Comment: I've seen the modification, but, what do you mean by a get action ? Like get, set ?

Comment: for rendering your page. It is called GET action, the action method which handles your form submit is called HttpPost action ( see i decorated the second method with that attribute). Just copy and paste the above code in your controller and run it, **I suggest you do some reading on how ASP.NET MVC works**. Trust me, It is going to save your time !

Comment: Ok thanks for that help ! I've already read about it, but still have some difficulties, but with time i'll pass them !

Comment: I put that code in my controllers view but when i click nothing appends that's strange

Comment: when you click on the button ? Are you sure it is not doing a form posting ?

Comment: Is it a submit button inside a form as i wrote in the answer ?

Comment: Yes it is ! It's in a form

Comment: If it is inside a form., It should submit the form when you click submit button. I don't know what is different in your environment.

Comment: And on the submit it should check in controller if my number in case is 1 ?

Comment: that is what the httppost action method is doing.did you even try it ? I suggest you to read the basics of MVC before writing any further code.

Comment: I know that the httppost is doing it but it's not working